# Section 6.6. Tu's Introduction to manifolds, definition of partial derivative.

Tags: definition, partial-derivative, smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces

I have an issue with understanding the notation of the following definition of partial derivative

$$
\left. \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \right|_{p} f := \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(p) := \frac{\partial \left( f \circ  \phi^{-1} \right)}{\partial r^i}(\phi(p)) := \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial r^i} \right|_{\phi(p)} \left( f \circ  \phi^{-1} \right).
$$

What I cannot really figure is if the following is actually well posed

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(p) := \frac{\partial \left( f \circ  \phi^{-1} \right)}{\partial r^i}(\phi(p))
$$

Because I don't really understand the meaning, to me the idea should be to transform the partial derivative of a function defined on a manifold to a partial derivative of a function defined in a open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Now if we look at the RHS of the last equation I wrote we have $f \circ \phi^{-1}$, which is a function from an open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$, however the variable w.r.t. we differentiate is also a function from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$.

My question is, why is such definition well posed?

Comment: what you mean by "well posed"? The definition of the partial derivative is just the partial derivative transported to an euclidean space, so it is well-defined as a function. Moreover: this partial derivative holds the properties of a derivation, as you should verify

Comment: I tried to explain at my best what I meant with "well posed". I also highlighted the specific part of the definition that puzzles me and why.

Comment: By standard coordinate, I think he means the usual projection map to the ith coordinate. I am almost certain you do this without it. I like to offer a different view. If you recall from calculus, you often do implicit differentiation on surfaces $f(x,y,z) = 1$, it is usually assumed that $y = y(x)$, but we often also treat $y$ as a variable to compute $\partial_y f$

Answer (score 3):

Let $g = f \circ \phi^{-1} : V\to \mathbb R$ which is defined on an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$. The meaning of
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x^i}$$
is clear (although in multivariable analysis usually $x_i$ is written instead of $x^i$). Tu writes it in the form
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial r^i}$$
to avoid confusion with the local coordinates $x^i$ on $U$ introduced by $\phi : U \to V$. It is just the usual partial derivative of $g(r^1,\ldots,r^n)$ with respect to the $i$-th coordinate.

I think you are confused because Tu says

> If $r^1,\ldots,r^n$ are the standard coordinates on $\mathbb R^n$, then $x^i = r^i \circ \phi$.

We may of course regard the $r^i$ and $x^i$ as *coordinate functions* living on $V$ and $U$, but this does not affect the meaning of $\frac{\partial g}{\partial r^i}$. You must not interpret this as a special case of an expression $\frac{\partial g}{\partial \psi}$ where $\psi : U \to  \mathbb R$ is some function - such a concept does not exist.

Comment: well the derivative respect to a function is an old concept, it indeed exists, but im not sure if this concept is compatible with this context

Comment: @Masacroso It makes of course sense with respect to a function $\beta : (a, b) \to U$, but it is not known to me how to generalize this to functions living on $U$. One could perhaps define $\frac{\partial g}{\partial \psi}(r) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(r+h) -g(r)}{\psi(r+h) - \psi(r)}$, but this would not be compatible with $\frac{\partial g}{\partial r^i}$.

Comment: Need to read through your answer. Thank you

Comment: @PaulFrost Could please help me to understand the following better? In the answer, $\partial g/ \partial r^i$ means the differentiation of $g$ with respect to $r^i$, where $r^i:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function. Here, $g = g(r^1, \cdots, r^n)$ is a function of functions $r^i$. If we are given an explicit form of $g$, then we can differentiate it and get an expression, in general, in terms of $r^1, r^2, \cdots r^n$; which can be considered as a function with domain $\mathbb{R}^n$ and hence can be evaluated at $\phi(p)$, $p\in U$. This is understanding correct?