# Question about derivative of a real-valued function on a manifold

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, information-theory, information-geometry

[image]

I am reading Methods of Information Geometry by " Shun-Ichi Amari",
I got stuck in the following line that I have underlined in the image as you can see.
My question is we have a real-valued function $f: S\to \mathbb{R}$ and we have $[\xi^i]$ to be the global coordinate of $S$, we have $\varphi: S\to \varphi(S)\subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$ so now we have the composition $f\circ\varphi^{-1}:\varphi(S)\to \mathbb{R}$ which the author is representing by $\bar{f}=f\circ \varphi^{-1}$, I am a bit confused in the partial derivative of $\bar{f}$ since it is a function from $\varphi(S)\subseteq \mathbb{R^n}\to \mathbb{R}$ so according to me we should differentiate it with respect to the coordinate of $\mathbb{R^n}$. Still, here they are differentiating with respect to the coordinates of $S$? what am I missing here? In my opinion, if we let $u^{i}$ be the coordinate of $\mathbb{R^n}$ then $\frac{\partial f\circ\varphi}{\partial u^i}$.So I guess the author is also taking $[\xi^i]$ as a coordinate of $\varphi$? is it?

Comment: Notice that (as you say) $\varphi(S)$ is a subset of $\Bbb{R}^n$, so $\xi_i$ are coordinates on $\Bbb{R}^n$. The author is only using the symbol "$\xi$" for the function $\overline{f}$, not $f$ itself, because they are being careful to say that $\xi$ are coordinates in $\Bbb{R}^n$.

Comment: can you elaborate on your answer, I am still confused, I agree that $\xi^{i}$ is a coordinate of $\mathbb{R^n}$ but according to the definition $\xi^{i}$ are also a coordinate of $S$ right so taking the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $\xi$ what we did is define $f\circ \varphi$ and took the partial derivative of this function with respect to $\xi^{i}$ and the compose it with $\varphi$,it means we are considering the same coordinate for both $\varphi$ and $S$,am I right?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, notation is a bit sloppy. The author considers a chart
$\varphi: U \to V \subset \mathbb R^n$ on $S$ and writes it in the form $\varphi = [\xi^i]$, where the $\xi^i : U \to \mathbb R$ are the coordinate functions of $\varphi$. At the same time he also writes $\bar f(\xi^1,\ldots,\xi^n)$ which suggests that these $\xi^i$ are the $n$ coordinate variables of $\bar f$.

This is in fact ambiguous: $\xi^i$ denotes both a *coordinate function* (which needs an input $s \in U$ to produce a real number $\xi^i(s)$) and a *variable* of the function $\bar f : V \to \mathbb R^n$.

As you I would prefer to use other symbols like $u^i$ for the variables of $\bar f$. Anyway, if you understand the notational ambiguity, it should not be a problem to correctly interpret $\frac{\partial \bar f}{\partial \xi^i}$. And be aware that the variable names used as arguments for $\bar f$ do not play any role. If the $i$-variable has the name $n$, then we write $\frac{\partial \bar f}{\partial n}$ for the $i$-th partial derivative of $\bar f$. This leads to notations like $\frac{\partial \bar f}{\partial x^i}$ (which seems to be the most popular variant), $\frac{\partial \bar f}{\partial u^i}$, $\frac{\partial \bar f}{\partial y}$ etc. *for the same thing*. Concerning the use of variable names also have a look to [Difficulty understanding Chain rule in multivariable calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4552724).

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4348387) is a similar question which might be worth studying.